# ICS in Exchange/Outlook updates not working

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, icalendar

I have generated an ICS file with an appointment (example 1). This appointment can change often so I would like to send out new ICS files (using my backend). This would normally work by sending the file with the same appointment UID and a higher SEQUENCE (example 2). This works great with iCloud Calendar where the existing item gets moved to the new date but does NOT work with Exchange/Google Calendar.

**Any ideas in how to make ICS updates update the existing calendar item in Exchange (without complicated subscriptions/setting up a webcal server)?**

Example 1: Initial ICS

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:2211@planning.company.nl
SUMMARY:Planning Item 01
DTSTAMP:20191123T170300Z
DTSTART:20191123T123000Z
DTEND:20191123T143000Z
SEQUENCE:1
DESCRIPTION:Planning Item 01
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Example 2: Updated ICS

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:adamgibbons/ics
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:2211@planning.company.nl
SUMMARY:Planning Item 01
DTSTAMP:20191129T170300Z
DTSTART:20191129T123000Z
DTEND:20191129T143000Z
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:Planning Item 01
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

While the DTSTAMP in example 2 is after the one in example 1, your SEQUENCE is backward (initial = 1, update = 0).